# Progress Dialog dismiss upon leaving helper class

Tags: android, progressdialog

So, I have an activity that starts a progress dialog by calling a method.

```
 private void showProgressDialog(){
    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setTitle("Computing");
    progress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    progress.setCancelable(true);
    progress.show();
}
```

After that, a helper class method is called... any one of five helper class methods (each residing in its own class) depending on the user preference.  Each of the helper class methods performs some code that can take up to a dozen seconds (progress dialog on screen the whole time) and then starts another activity.  In other words, the `startActivity()` call is not from the class in which the progress dialog was originally called.

I never directly dismiss the progress dialog. However, the dialog always goes away (seemingly being dismissed by itself at the `startActivity()` call).  This has caused no issues and I am happy with how it looks/responds.  Leak canary has not identified a leak with this pattern (anti-pattern).

Am I OK with this?

Comment: _startActivity() call is not from the activity in which the progress dialog was originally called_ - are you sure about that? Also, are you sure you're not calling `finish()` anywhere?

Comment: Yeah, I meant "class" not activity.  Thanks, I edited my post.   And yes, I'm sure that the start activity is called in the helper class, not the original activity class.

Answer (score 0):

public  void DialogCargando(Context context,boolean state){

```
    if(state){
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context,R.style.DialogProgressBar_01);
        //Intaciamos ala clase progressDialog para ejecutar dialogo cargando
        // mDialog.setTitle("Mensaje");
        mDialog.setMessage("Espere por favor cargando...");
        mDialog.show();

    }else {
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: es un método recibe true para activar false para hacer dismiss debes de instanciar a la clase